# Install Window 8.1 on VirtualBox

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, iso-image, windows-8

A relative of mine bought a new Mac but needs Windows for certain tasks. I have a set-up on my Mac where Windows 7 is running inside VirtualBox. So I agreed to help her put a similar set up on her Mac.

She bought [Windows 8.1 Pro Student](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/mseea/en_IE/pdp/Windows-8.1-Pro-Student/productID.288573500) from the Microsoft Store and I generated an ISO from the .exe download.

However, it looks like this will only install over an existing Windows installation. The ISO doesn't appear to be capable of doing a fresh install over clean system.

Do Microsoft sell install disks capable of doing a fresh installs of Windows anymore? Any ideas on where I could get an ISO to install Windows on VirtualBox? Or any on how to progress from here?

Comment: which issue does she have in detail? Is the ISO not booting?

Comment: The ISO boots but reports that it cannot find Windows already installed on the system.